# Ruby on Rails - Randomly failing RSpec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Sorry for my stupid question.

I added the external api to get response in order to check zipcode's validation.

app/validators/zipcode_validator.rb

```
class ZipcodeValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    record.errors.add(:zipcode, :blank) if record.zipcode.blank?
    record.errors.add(:zipcode, :not_found) if WmsService.wms_delivery_dates(record.zipcode).nil?
  end 
end
```

It works fine in real but failed randomly and took more time when I run rspec.

What's the good solution for this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not call external APIs in your tests. There are several methods to avoid it:

1. [VCR gem](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) records API response in first call then then replies it from disk (that is fast and reliable).
2. Mocking HTTP calls, e.g. with [WebMock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock). You need to write specify mocked request and write a response in your specs. It may help you improve test readability also it helps in testing edge cases.
3. Wrap your service call in your class and replace it with an RSpec stub.
4. Wrap your service call in your class that accepts adapters. An adapter is responsible for calling external service. In test env pass a test adapter with predetermined responses.