# How to test Rails app with a Gem that is making API calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I wrote a simple gem that calls an API. I use this custom gem in a Model Validation to check whether someone exists on the API. If not, there should be a validation error.

I'm now trying to create my RSpec tests, but having some difficulties understanding how to write the unit test.

The validation rule in my User model looks like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  validate :check_webservice

  def check_webservice
    result = MyGem::ApiCall(name)
    errors.add(:name, "error") unless result.is_valid?
  end
end
```

I tried using VCR in my Unit test to record the API call, but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas how I should tackle this?

```
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do

  let(:user) { build(:user) }

  it "is valid with valid attributes" do
    VCR.use_cassette("verified user") do
      expect(user).to be_valid
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53609912/580346

Comment: Thanks, it seemed it was recording, but you need to set the folder relative to the Rails root. My bad.